# .... form the foundation of a child’s development throughout their growing up.

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis

Can I use the above structure...  i.e. 'throughout **their growing up**'

Comment: It would be better if you gave the complete sentence. There's nothing wrong with the fragment grammatically, but there is a hint of redundancy, and 'as they grow up' is more idiomatic (less highfalutin') than 'throughout their growing up'.

Comment: Forming foundations ought to be followed by something more constructive. It is a mixed metaphor as is, "Now, I'll wash my hands of the matter and lay it to rest."

Answer (score 2):

No you may not.  For I am the God of English and I say thee, nay!

Is it an issue of grammar?  No, it is not your grammar I find wanting.

Is it an issue of structure?  No, it is not your structure I find wanting.

Is it an issue of meaning? No, it is not your meaning I find wanting.

Is it an issue of style? Yes! Think about what you're doing to this beautiful bastardized language of mine. Others may follow your example.

> ... form the foundation of a child's development throughout their growing up.

can lead to

> ... form the foundation of a child's development throughout their school attending.

can lead to

> ... form the foundation of a child's development throughout their diaper pooping.

And no one wants that.

Why?

Idioms. Keep talking like this and it may catch on, and I'll feel like gouging out my eyes every time I see it imitated.  A host of well loved idioms are orbiting this sentence fragment looking up at me asking if this is what things have come to.

> ... form the foundation of a child's development throughout their early years.

and

> ... form the foundation of a child's development throughout their formative years.

and

> ... form the foundation of a child's development throughout their adolescence

But even as I smile upon these idioms the soul of Ernest Hemingway stirs.  I know what is coming.  I know he is right.  He draws his sword of the empty string. The meaning stands, unafraid.  He strikes.  Vowels and consonants scatter like gouts of blood.

I hear Hemingway's sword slide back into its scabbard and I see the remnants.

> ... form the foundation of a child's development.

And indeed, I'm hard pressed to say the meaning has changed.  Damn that man could write.

Comment: Many thanks for helping me to understand this, and thanks also for your enthusiasm!  As English is my second language, idioms will always confuse me as I know it's something I've heard but cannot be sure if the grammar is correct, which is why I turned to this page for clarification, and I sure got clarification alright :)

Comment: Fair warning. ELU is not a proof-reading service, nor a copy editing service.  So don't get used to this sort of treatment.  Idiom choices can signal the difference between good and bad without changing the literal meaning.  Idioms are the well worn path we take to meaning.  Nothing says you can't wander off that path.  Nothing says you won't leave your audience feeling lost by doing so.  Learn the idioms.  You may break them, but please, not carelessly, not out of ignorance.  Break them for fun.  Some of our best jokes are subverted idioms.